# Does this account for daylight savings?

Tags: java

```
// someTime is epoch in millis (UTC)

final long timeNow = new Date().getTime();
final long midnight = timeNow - timeNow % (3600 * 24 * 1000L);
final long yesterdayMidnight = midnight - (3600 * 24 * 1000L);


// check if same day.
if (someTime >= midnight)
   // do something

// check if yesterday
if (someTime >= yesterdayMidnight)
```

**Edited:** My purpose is to check whether someTime is in the same day or in the previous day without doing too much heavyweight stuff.

Does this account for day light savings and why? If not, what's the simplest logic?

Comment: If you say new Date(); , it means you are referring to your system's current date.  Whatever your system's date is set to , you will get that time only.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I believe the question is in fact "is it safe to use this code having in mind possible daylight saving switch".

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? We can't easily give you good code to achieve the results you want without knowing the aim.

Comment: You calculate in UTC timezone which has no daylight saving time by definition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current code doesn't do *anything* with the local time zone - everything is in UTC, effectively (certainly in terms of your code, which is dealing in "milliseconds since the Unix epoch").

If you want to make your code time-zone-sensitive, you should use (in order of preference):

- Java 8's `java.time` (look at [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) for example)
- [Joda Time](http://joda.org/joda-time)
- `java.util.Calendar` with `java.util.TimeZone`

Use higher-level abstractions where possible - your code should do as little low-level manipulation of time as possible.

EDIT: Now that we know the purpose, here's an example implementation in Joda Time:

```
public void calculate(Instant now, Instant then, DateTimeZone zone) {
    LocalDate today = new LocalDate(now, zone);
    LocalDate otherDay = new LocalDate(then, zone);
    if (otherDay.equals(today)) {
        // Today day
    } else if (otherDay.equals(today.minusDays(1)) {
        // Yesterday
    } else {
        // Neither today nor yesterday
    }
}
```

Note how there's nothing low level here - we're just working out which date each value (now and then) falls in within the given time zone, and then comparing those.

Answer (score 0):

Your check will fail in some cases having in mind daylight savings. Let's assume it is now 5 o' clock on the day when daylight saving happens and at 3 o'clock we've switched the clock forward. Therefor only 4 hours have passed since midnight but it is in fact 5. So `midnight` in your code will be a time `5` hours ago. This means that if `someTime` is between 5 hours ago and 4 hours ago(e.g. 4 hours and a half ago) when it's in fact been yesterday your algorithm will report it has been today.

Answer (score 0):

That does not seem to be correct from daylight savings point. First, what's the timezone of someTime date? What about the days/nights(in fact) when the daylight savings take place (one hour +/-)?
If you use Joda lib there is a convenient method DateTime.isBefore() that will return whether one date is before another.